# To show a set is positive Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $P\subset [0,1]$ be a set of positive Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}$. How to show that the set
$$E=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times [0,1]:x-y\in P\}$$
is also set of positive Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: By Fubini's Theorem the measure of this set is $\int m(\{x: x-y \in P\})dy$ and $m(\{x: x-y \in P\})=m(P)$ for each $y$. So the measure is actually $\infty$, not just positive!

Comment: Right. Let me put some more restriction to make $E$ finite positive measure.

Comment: Now the $m(E)=m(P).$ right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Comment: Sir does $P$ closed implies $E$ closed?

Comment: I guess yes as$(x_n,y_n)\to (x,y)$ implies $x_n-y_n\to x-y$ so $x-y\in P$ as $P$ is closed

Comment: It is the inverse imge of $P$ under the continuous map $(x,y) \to x-y$ so it is closed.